# searching the table by family using sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, duplicates

I have this table named `table`:

```
+-----+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
| id  |       money        |  family  |     date     | user |
+-----+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
|  1  |  credit card       |       1  | 2018-01-04   | U123 |
|  2  |  direct transfert  |       1  | 2018-01-04   | U123 |
|  3  |  Wire transfert    |       1  | 2018-01-06   | U123 |
|  4  |  Exchange          |       2  | 2018-01-03   | U123 |
|  5  |  free              |       2  | 2018-01-03   | U123 |
|  6  |  other             |       3  | 2018-01-08   | U123 |
+-----+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
```

What I want is to always get the result by family. For example if I search the `date >= 2018-01-06` I want to get this table:

```
+-----+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
| id  |       money        |  family  |     date     | user |
+-----+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
|  1  |  credit card       |       1  | 2018-01-04   | U123 |
|  2  |  direct transfert  |       1  | 2018-01-04   | U123 |
|  3  |  Wire transfert    |       1  | 2018-01-06   | U123 |
|  6  |  other             |       3  | 2018-01-08   | U123 |
+-----+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
```

I tried this query:

```sql
SELECT e.* 
  FROM table e 
 WHERE e.user ='U123' AND e.family IN 
(
    SELECT e2.family 
      FROM table e2 
     WHERE (e2.date >= "2018-01-06") 
) 
 ORDER BY family;
```

But I receive this result:

```
+-----+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
| id  |       money        |  family  |     date     | user |
+-----+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
|  1  |  credit card       |       1  | 2018-01-04   | U123 |
|  2  |  direct transfert  |       1  | 2018-01-04   | U123 |
|  3  |  Wire transfert    |       1  | 2018-01-06   | U123 |
|  4  |  Exchange          |       2  | 2018-01-03   | U123 |
|  5  |  free              |       2  | 2018-01-03   | U123 |
|  6  |  other             |       3  | 2018-01-08   | U123 |
+-----+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
```

You see the id number `4` and `5` shouldn't be there.

In addition I want to be able to add other conditions like that:

```sql
SELECT e.*
  FROM table e 
 WHERE e.user ='U123' AND e.family IN 
(
    SELECT e2.family 
      FROM table e2 
     WHERE (e2.date >= "2018-01-06") 
       AND (e2.money like "%transf%")
)
 ORDER BY family;
```

And still have the results by family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your query is that the sub-query used for the `IN` also selects the "family" from other users.

You could fix that by including the user.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourtable e 
WHERE e.user = 'U123'
  AND (e.user, e.family) IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT e2.user, e2.family 
    FROM yourtable e2 
    WHERE e2.date >= '2018-01-06'
  )
ORDER BY family;
```

But in this case it's probably better to use an `EXISTS` instead.
One that links on the user & family.

Then put those extra criteria in the EXISTS query.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourtable e 
WHERE e.user = 'U123'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourtable e2
    WHERE e2.user = e.user
      AND e2.family = e.family
      AND e2.date >= '2018-01-06'
      -- AND e2.money LIKE '%transf%'
  )
ORDER BY family;
```

Test on RexTester [here](https://rextester.com/TTBS91962)

Comment: thank you very much for the response it helped me indeed :) :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your selections is that you also need to filter the subquery by the same username, e.g.:

```sql
select e.* 
from table e 
where e.user ='u123' and e.family in 
(
    select distinct e2.family 
    from table e2 
    where 
        e2.user ='u123' and 
        e2.date >= '2018-01-06'
) 
order by e.family
```

```sql
select e.*
from table e 
where e.user ='u123' and e.family in 
(
    select distinct e2.family 
    from table e2 
    where 
        e2.user ='u123' and 
        e2.date >= '2018-01-06' and
        e2.money like '%transf%'
)
order by e.family
```

Comment: thank you very much for responding i choose to work with the first answer as it is more simple, :)